# Loop through by checking a flag

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to write yahtzee game in python,

I have already created a working game but it works by following a list so user cant choose what he/she wants to play. I am trying to change the algorithm.

Here what Im trying, for the following 2d array

```
lower_part = [[1, "2 PAIRS", "2P", False],
[2, "3 OF A KIND", "3K", False],
[3, "4 OF A KIND", "4K", False],
[4, "FULL HOUSE", "FH", False],
[5, "LOW STRAIGHT", "LS", False],
[6, "HIGH STRAIGHT", "HS", False],
[7, "YAHTZEE", "YZ", True],
[8, "CHANCE", "CH", False]]
```

I want to listen user input like:

```
print('Pleasee Choose a game to play:')
for index, game_name, game_code, is_played in lower_part:
    print(f'{index} : {game_name}')

keep_game_no = int(input(f'{index} : {game_name}'))
```

--

```
At this moment user already played a game and rolled the dice 3 times and I kept dice list to process so I want to process the dice list by comparing their input ( game choice) above. THats where actually I stuck..
```

then when they choose one of those games I want to update that game flag as TRUE and next time exclude it from looping again.

However I know it is not suggested to change the array which is already being used in iteration.

Any suggestion?

Should I use two arrays? or a tuple then derive a dynamic array from tuple to use?

appreciate your assist.

Kind Regards

Comment: It looks like you don't need modify the list while iterating on it. `game_no = input('what game?'); lower_part[game_no][-1] = True` (although as a sidenote, a dict seems like a much more appropriate data-structure to use in this case)

Comment: You could slice the array to create a copy. Or you could store the number of the played games in a set, or even a list if you want, and compare the chosen game to the set to reject duplicate input (ask to input again).

Comment: Thanks for quick responses, Matt you right I dont have to loop through the list because it will be a random choice so I can use dictionary and assume that user input is the "key" to reach the dict. isnt it? then I can change the value of it.. When user plays all of 8 games I can reset the dictionary values back to False or anything else for the purpose so that next game starts from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

I have used a copy of the original game dictionary then removed the played games from copy dict and bringing the left games in copy i wrote the code.

```
lower = {
    "2 PAIRS" : False,
    "3 OF A KIND" : False,
    "4 OF A KIND" : False,
    "FULL HOUSE" : False,
    "LOW STRAIGHT" : False,
    "HIGH STRAIGHT" : False,
    "YAHTZEE" : False,
    "CHANCE" : False}

lower_copy = copy.deepcopy(lower)

for i in range(len(lower_copy)):
    keep_game_no = input(f'Which Game:\n {lower_copy.keys()}')

    if keep_game_no:
        print(f'You Have Chosen{keep_game_no}')
        lower_copy[keep_game_no] = True  #this one i can use without pop see below
        lower_copy.pop(keep_game_no)
        print(lower_copy.items())

lower_comp = {k:v for (k,v) in lower_copy.items() if not v} # for second solution
```

I am also considering now to update values not to pop them and use dict comprehension with a condition like in the last row above.

Which one is better I dont know. your comments are valuable. Thanks a lot for your precious time!